# How do I map a spherical triangle to a plane triangle?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, gis, platform-independent

The gnomonic projection maps spherical triangles to straight-edged plane triangles.

But I've heard that the Chamberlin trimetric projection has less distortion, so I'd like to use that instead.
Alas, when I use my (extremely rough and probably buggy) implementation of Chamberlin trimetric projection to map the spherical triangle formed by its 3 base points to the plane, I seem to be getting a shape that is *almost* a triangle, but the three "lines" curve and bulge out.
Is that a bug in my code, or is it supposed to do that?

Is there some other way of mapping a spherical triangle to a straight-edged plane triangle that has less distortion than the gnomonic projection?

EDIT:
My goal here is to make a custom ["polyhedral map"](http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Normal/ProjPoly/projPoly.html) of Earth.
If you print out something from the ["Map Fold-outs"](http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Normal/ProjPoly/Foldout/foldout.html) page, you will have something almost exactly like what I'm trying to make.

I have 2 triangles.
One is a spherical triangle drawn on a 3D globe.
By definition, each edge of a spherical triangle is part of a great circle.
When you look at that 3D globe, there are a bunch of cities, coastlines, etc. that are (hopefully) accurately plotted on that 3D globe, inside that spherical triangle.

The other triangle is a flat, plane (2D), straight-edged, Euclidean triangle. On paper.
At the moment the interior of that triangle is blank white paper, but eventually I want to draw a copy of all those cities, coastlines, etc. into that area.

Every map projection will map that 3D spherical triangle to a 2D image. Then it's easy to (in 2D) rotate and slide and shrink, and perhaps skew, that image until the 3 corners exactly line up with the 3 corners of my plane triangle.
If I stack the results of a bunch of different map projections on top of each other,
even though I've forced the 3 corners to exactly line up,
each projection will put the cities in a slightly different location.
Unfortunately, many projections take cities that are slightly inside the spherical triangle and draw them slightly outside the flat 2D triangle.
(One symptom of this problem is that the sides of the spherical triangle
are mapped to plane (2D) curves whose endpoints match the corners properly, but they bulge outward slightly from perfectly straight lines drawn between the corners).
That leads to the city being completely missing from my polyhedral map.

I'd rather not run the risk of some Polish mathematician getting upset that Warsaw is inexplicably missing from the flat, plane (2d), paper map that I've made :-).

So I'm looking for map projections that "keep it inside the lines".
I need 3 specific great circles (the edges of the spherical triangle) to be mapped to straight lines on paper.
I don't care about *other* great circles -- straight, non-straight, whatever.

I hear that the map projection used for the [Dymaxion map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dymaxion_map) meets that criteria; and someone told me that he *thought* it used the Chamberlin trimetric projection.
But apparently either (a) I'm using the wrong equations -- so where can I find the right equations? Or (b) Dymaxion actually uses some other projection -- so where can I find the equations for that projection?

What map projections meet that criteria?
And can you give me a link to the (x,y) = f(lat, long) equations for that projection?

I'm looking for answers of the form
"The gnomonic projection meets your criteria. The [gnomonic projection equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection)."

Comment: Isn't some kind of curve inherent in using non-Euclidean triangles? I suppose intuitively, I'd expect each edge of a triangle to be part of a great circle - are these "bulges" relative to that?

Comment: I won't be able to answer this regardless ;-) but for those of us that are curious is there any chance you can link in an image or two to indicate what you are getting vs. What you want to get?

Comment: I added a link to some pretty images to indicate what I want to get.
Steve, I added (probably far too many) details to the question statement -- does that answer your questions?

Answer (score 2):

I've just looked here...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamberlin_trimetric_projection

I think the key words are "The projection's principal feature is that it compromises between distortions of area, direction, and distance." - in particular "compromises".

In any projection from a Euclidean to a non-Euclidean surface, there *must* be distortions. The issue isn't "how much distortion" so much as "what kind". Gnomic projection presumably makes no compromises in terms of preserving the linearity of lines, but therefore has more of other kinds of distortion.

Not my field, though, so I could be missing the point.

**EDIT** I can't help noticing that in the illustration on the Wikipedia page, the latitude and longitude lines aren't straight lines.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I see that most of the the meridians (lines of longitude) are not straight, and so the Chamberlin trimetric does not map *every* great circle to a straight line -- only gnomic projection does that.
However, I (incorrectly?) believed that the Chamberlin trimetric does map *some* great circles to straight lines -- in particular, the great circles between each pair of control points.
It's not obvious to me from that illustration whether those three great circles are mapped to straight lines or not.

Answer (score 2):

I've been there and I know is absolutly not a single perfect projection for the thing you it... Absolutly none. BUT there are some better than others.

Your best shot is an auto oriented stereographic. First you should find the centroid of the polygon you want to project and then use the stereographic projection centered on that axe.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StereographicProjection.html

In thouse two you will find most of the things you need to, but I'm warning you, it will not be beautiful and it will hurt a lot.

In the end the only real solution is operating directly in 3D but that requires really advanced geometry that is not found under the rocks or the supermarket.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the title*, because I don't fully understand the question body.

Answer is : you can't. You won't be able to map the sphere to the plane while keeping the same geodesics (great circles <-> straight lines). The latter is flat, the former is curved.

If you could map geodesics to geodesics, the two surfaces would have the same (intrinsic) curvature, and they have not.

(*) not quite: I answer "Can I map all triangles of a sphere to triangles of the plane sensibly".

Comment: The gnomonic projection does, in fact, map "segments of great circles on the sphere" to "straight line segments on the plane".
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/gnomonic_projection .

Comment: Mmm, you're right. The gnomonic projection can't map the entire sphere to a plane all at once. Bummer.
It looks like I'm going to have to chop up the entire sphere into spherical triangles, and then independently map each spherical triangle to a different plane.

Which projection(s) could I use?

Answer (score 1):

All map projections distort some or all of area, distance and bearings between points.  As you note the gnomonic projection maps (arcs of) great circles to straight lines, so it will map a spherical triangle to a plane triangle.  It is the only projection which has this property.  It is also true that a straight line on a gnomonic chart is an arc of a great circle.

This property inevitably means that there will be distortions in other aspects of a gnomonic chart.

Comment: I agree that the gnomonic projection is the only projection that maps *every* great circle to a straight line.
However, I disagree with the implication that it is the only projection that can map a spherical triangle to a plane triangle.
Both the Collignon projection and the Peirce quincuncial projection can map an octant (a spherical triangle with 90 degree corners) to a straight-edged plane triangle.
See http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Normal/ProjPCyl/projPCyl.html#Collignon and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce_quincuncial_projection for details.

Comment: @David: You're right, I should have written 'The gnomonic projection is the only projection which will map every spherical triangle to a plane triangle.'  Thanks for pointing out the inadequacies of my use of existential qualifiers.